# Craft not generating language links correctly

Tags: localization

`{{siteUrl}}`, `{{category.url}}`, `{{product.url}}`, etc. is not outputting any language.

The main language is Norwegian. I created a folder for English (/en/) with `define('CRAFT_LOCALE', 'en_us');`

Navigating to `site.com/en` works fine, and all the english content shows as expected. However any link generated by craft simply omits "/en/", thus throwing me back to Norwegian. I don't get it.

Anything in particular I should look into? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you [define your `siteUrls`](https://craftcms.com/docs/localization-guide#step-4-define-your-site-uRLs)? The array keys for `siteUrl` should correspond to the locale keys, so in your case you'll probably need an entry like `'en_us' => 'http://example.dev/en/'`

Comment: Aha! My mistake was having "en" instead of "en_us". Thank you kindly!

Comment: Looks legit, I'm stumped. Never experienced an issue like that.

Comment: Awesome, Stian – I'll add my original comment as an answer, then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a multilingual site, your [`siteUrl` config setting](https://craftcms.com/docs/localization-guide#step-4-define-your-site-uRLs) in `/craft/config/general.php` needs to be an array where the keys correspond to your installed locales:

```
return array(
    // ...
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'no' => 'http://example.com/',
        'en_us' => 'http://example.com/en/',
    ),
);
```